# 500 OOPS: cannot open config file:/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Tags: ftp-server

I don't know why it cannot open config file.

```
$ ll /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 xuehui1 root 4182 Aug 20  2012 /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf //exits
$ sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
500 OOPS: cannot open config file:/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Here is vsftpd.conf,and it works well other linux machines(centos) but this one?Any help would be appreciated..

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format
xferlog_std_format=YES
#
chroot_local_user=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
#enable for standalone mode
listen=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
use_localtime=YES
```

Comment: facing same issue.. any solution for this?

Comment: sudo chown root /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is problem about file's owner. U should set correct owner for config `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

```
sudo chown root /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Comment: Oops...Not running `service` as `sudo` was the _root_ cause. :p

Answer (score 9):

Use `service vsftpd [start/restart/stop]`, not simply `vsftpd [start/restart/stop]`

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the OS, you may get the following error because of the incorrect command being run.
For example, I ran the following command in Linux Mint 15:

```
sudo vsftpd restart
```

The output I received was:

```
500 OOPS: cannot read config file: restart
```

The **correct** command to restart vsftpd daemon was:

```
sudo restart vsftpd
```

This gave the output:

```
vsftpd start/running, process 2231
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to start vsftpd with the systemctl command.

```
sudo systemctl start vsftpd
```

Answer (score 1):

### You are probably getting this error because of xinetd ftp is running.

**The procedure mentioned below will resolve the following errors:**

- **vsftpd Error** : 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket
- **ncftpget Error** : Server hangup immediately after connect

**Follow the procedure mentioned below to rectify the error:**

1. To View which ftp service is running use

   - $ lsof -i | grep ftp
2. To stop xinetd :

   - $ sudo service xinetd stop
3. After stoping xinetd restart your vsftpd service by typing :

   - $ /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart  (Become root and run this command)
4. Also check the vsftpd.conf with this one

   - listen=YES
   - local_enable=YES
   - write_enable=YES
   - local_umask=022
   - dirmessage_enable=YES
   - use_localtime=YES
   - xferlog_enable=YES
   - secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
   - pam_service_name=vsftpd
   - rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```
sudo restart vsftpd
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, a freshly installed vsftpd process fails with that message.  I have to tell it where my config file is:

`$ sudo vsftpd/3.0.3/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf &
[1] 5735`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd.service
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure vsftpd
```